# Change AppCompatSpinner popup background color

Tags: android, spinner

I tried to make `Spinner` with white text as my theme but when `Spinner` popup show then it has default white background so my text isn't visible there. I also tried to set with both `android:popupBackground` and `app:popupBackground` but it doesn't reflect there.

Screenshots of `Spinner` :

Spinner 1

[image]

Spinner Popup 2

[image: ![Spinner Popup 2]

## XML for spinner

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
    android:id="@+id/spinLocation"
    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:popupBackground=""
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/white" />
```

## XML for Spinner Item

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/txtValue"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingBottom="7dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="7dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp" />
```

I know it is because of item `textColor` but if I do not define it then it showing in popup but not proper in `Spinner`. So suggest me a best approach for this and also suggest for header if `appCompatSpinner` supports it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set themes, or create a custom one.

Here is a sample code:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:entries="@array/array_radius"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you can add your own Textview for spinner

```
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/carMake"
                android:textColor="#606060"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/vin_border"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="14dp">

            </Spinner>
```

java for adding items

```
 List<String> model = new ArrayList<>();
    model.add("Ford");
    model.add("BMW");
    model.add("Audi");
    model.add("Hyundai");
    model.add("Suzuki");
    model.add("Porsche");

ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), R.layout.spinner_textview_layout, model);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    carMake.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

textview for spinner item

```
<com.tagx.view.CustomTextView
app:font="@string/monte_light"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:maxLines="1"
style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:paddingStart="=20dp"
android:paddingEnd="40dp"
android:textColor="@color/fragment_owner_title_color"
android:layout_gravity="end"
android:textSize="12sp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
/>
```